# Is there a way to make all these polygons symmetrical?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

So I am doing a side project for fun. How can I make these points on the trees all go up vertically without having to manually edit each one?

They are made using the pen tool so each of the different color sections is one object. They are crooked and I want them to be all be standing up straight (the triangles regular).

[image]

Comment: Hmm the colors inverted for some reason when I uploaded but doesnt really matter.

Comment: What does "go up vertically" mean??? Move them vertical? How the objects are constructed will have a great deal to do with that. Ultimately, it's going to require selecting anchors if you want to move anchors.

Comment: Sorry I wrote the question really poorly. They are made using the pen tool so each of the different color sections is one object. They are crooked and I want them to  be all be standing up straight.

Comment: so you want the upper central point to be in the middle of the two lower ones?

Comment: As an  aside, "perfect" forms, angles and such tend to look less real than imperfect forms, because very little in nature grows uniformly. I don't know what you're going for, so I'm not recommending anything, but I would usually try to see a more finished product before tweaking finer details.

Comment: one could script this

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple solution to normalizing the existing paths you have. It would be a tedious process of selecting anchors then aligning and distributing them. Then selecting other anchors and repeating.

An easier method if you want perfectly distributed anchors and angles is to start with just a single path and then apply `Effect > Distort & Transform > Zig Zag` to create the angles, then use `Object > Expand Appearance` to get the zig zag "baked in" and finally adding three other anchors to close off the path and form shape to add a fill to.

[image]

You can then use `Free Transform` or manually distort the end result to accommodate overall angles needed.

You can also start with a path which is curved and angled to match the desired tree line, then follow these steps.

In short, it's easier to start over than to try and arrange what you already have.

But.. as @Dom pointed out in the comments, variations are going to look *much* more realistic than a bunch of even angles will.

Comment: Awesome idea thank you so much for the help! I'll post a finish version on here when I'm done!